# How to read multiple csv files into one data variable with each csv file being one entry in that variable?

Tags: r

How should csv files be read in R such that the entire content of csv file is one entry in the dataframe that is created?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-at-once

Answer (score 0):

Let there be multiple csv files in one directory. You get a list of tables like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- list.files("/my/data/dir") %>% map(read_csv)
```

or using base R:

```
data <- lapply(list.files("/my/data/dir"), read.csv)
```